# How to transform a string into multiple variables

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, variables

Is there a way to transform a string into multiple variables?
If I try:

```
string = "string1 string2 string3 string4"
string.split(" ")
```

I know that I will get an array:

```
=> ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]
```

But I need a piece of code to transform `string` into multiple strings, something like this:

```
string1 = "string1"
string2 = "string2"
string3 = "string3"
string4 = "string4"
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: variables can be assigned dynamically. But new variables with dynamic name can not be created

Comment: you can save it in an arrya or hash

Comment: I'm sure there is some trick that I can use to do that, but I'm a newbie so I couldn't find it, and that's why I asked here for help. And I need to turn the string into variables or multiple strings with names, so I can use any of them in particular, that's why an array wouldn't be useful....

Comment: If you know how many variables are to be created, and you explicitly create those variables, then the answer of 'megas' is correct.

Comment: I didn't said that the answer of @megas is incorrect, i'm sure is correct, but it's not usefull for me becuse I will use user input as string, so I don't know how many variables I have to create... is there a way to combine the `string.lenght` and @megas's solution or to transform the string into an array, use `array.length` to find out how much variables should be created and then to transform the array into a set of variables?

Comment: You will not get `["string1", "strng2", "string3", "string4"]`. You will get `["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]`.

Comment: @sawa , first, your comment makes no sense, second, why did you think my question is "doesn't show research effort, is unclear or unsefull", because I see that you gived an -1 calificative. If you think so, why you don't give me a solution to the problem? instead of making nonsense comments and unusefull question edits....

Comment: I don't get why you are claiming that my comment does not make sense. And, why do you think that I think that your `question is "doesn't show research effort, is unclear or unsefull [unuseful]"`, and how was it possible to see that I gived *[gave]* an *[a]* -1 calificative?

Comment: I know my English sucks, and I say that you comment doesn't makes sense because you should edit that, when you edited the entire question, insetead of posting the type mistake here. Anyway, I know that you **gave** me **a** -1 calificative because it coincides with the time when you edited my question, and it happened the same way with my previous question... I think you should fisr give me the solution and prove me how easy it is and after that you should give me an -1 calificative (wich is equal to saying "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or unusefull"), right?

Comment: Was that a type mistake? You didn't say so. How should I know your intent? And if it is indeed a type mistake, then such sloppyness would show that the question doesn't show research effort anyway.

Comment: Don't play innocent, it is obvious. And before commenting back, why you don't give me the solution that I'm waiting for, oh all-knowing sawa, god of ruby?

Comment: If you do have such kind of type mistakes, then that means your question is sloppy. You should not expect people to put effort into answering your question more than you put effort into writing the question.

Comment: Now, when the (only and almost unseenable) mistake is corrected, you can give me your wise solution **oh all-knowing @sawa, god of ruby** ... right?

Comment: I actually don't get what you are asking.

Comment: What you think about reading **the entire 9th comment** of this question? I explained there some things, especially to the end of the comment, and if you still don't get it you can call yourself silly and be sure that you will not be wrong!

Comment: Now, @sawa that I proved you that your -1 calificative makes no sense, if you are fair, I think you should remove it or even give me an +1 calificative. If you still think that I didn't proved anything or that your calificative makes sense, please read again our entire discussion, it will be mind--lightning for you, I'm sure.

Comment: Someone has to explain to me what is unclear about his question, I had no problem understanding it.

Comment: @bugerrorbug This style and behavior is not really welcome here. You are acting like you are in the kindergarten. Same thing goes to sawa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how:

```
string = "string1 string2 string3 string4"
string.split(' ').each do |s|
   instance_variable_set :"@#{s}", s
   self.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :"#{s}" }
end

string1 #=> "string1"
string2 #=> "string2"
```

Tested in IRB with `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x64-mingw32]`

Another way would be to store the result of the split in an array, and use a ghost method to mimic variable access.

Comment: Awesome! but it still haves some inconveniences: I tried             `string = "string1 string2 string3 string4"
string.split(' ').each do |s|
   instance_variable_set :"@#{s}", s
   self.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :"#{s}" }
   puts string1
   puts string2
end` and it prints "string1" and then gives me an error saying "undefined local variable or method "string2"" I tried then without`puts string2` and it prints four times "string1" (like `string1\nstring1\nstring1\nstring1\n`), can you tell me why?

Comment: @bugerrorbug Watch the position of your `end` keyword. Right now string1 works because the code above it just defined it, but string2 will only be defined after the next iteration! so the `end` must come before any access to a string# variable.

Comment: What you mean? because I just copy-pasted your code and then added the two "puts" methods, and when I copy-pasted it in the commnet, it looks that cramped, but the code that I tried is exactly like yours.

Comment: @bugerrorbug Copy/paste it now, you had the `end` keyword misplaced. (I added string2 check)

Comment: I found what was wrong: I placed the "puts" methods before the end, when I placed them after the end, it worked perfectly! thanks a lot! (and if you were talking about this when you said "`end` keyword misplaced", then sorry because I misunderstood what you said)

Comment: That's what I meant ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple assignment future:

```
string1, string2, string3, string4 = "string1 string2 string3 string4".split(" ")
```

Comment: I want to use as string user input, so I don't know how much string names I have to use.... anyway, that is a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

> And I need to turn the string into variables or multiple strings with
>   names, so I can use any of them in particular, that's why an array
>   wouldn't be useful

I know you're a newbie, so maybe you're not aware you can reference individual array elments just as you can separate variables?

```
string = "string1 string2 string3 string4"
my_words = string.split(" ")

if my_words[1] = "string2" 
  puts "I found 'string2' in the second word"
end
```

array elements are individually numbered from 0, 1, 2 up to ( my_words.size - 1 )

You can work backwards from the last array item by using negative numbers, so 
`my_words[-1]` contains "string4"

Comment: I my script, instead of numbered words, the string will contain user input, so I don't find your solution very usefull. I asked this question because I want to break the user input tring into words, check if the words contain a set of characters, print the words that contain that characters and then use that words for other purposes in the scrip. If you find another way to do that, than breaking the string into variables, you will be my Jedi master :))